# Does the knowledge of statistics and probability has applications in solving PDE numerically?

Tags: probability, statistics, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

I will take a course about numerical analysis next semester, but now I have a few quextions, my teacher who teach me statistics this semester told that we can use the theory of probability to evaluate integral in high dimensional and to estimate the errors, I want to know can we apply the knowledge of statistics and the theory of probability to estimate how accurate our numerical solution to a function is and to correct the solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Importance sampling can be used to estimate an integral, simulation techniques can be used to do versatile things, but I don’t think there is a connection between simulation and solving partial differential equations.